# How can I test if a layer is using SDE

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, feature-layer

I find that when things are not working as they should repairing the geometry on everything is a good first point of troubleshooting so I run a few lines of python:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    arcpy.RepairGeometry_management(lyr)
```

Of course this only works with certain layers, so to make this applicable when there are rasters I've added:

```
if lyr.isFeatureLayer == True:
```

But I still have the problem when there are SDE layers. How can I either test for SDE or test for layers that are a Shapefile or a feature class in a Personal or File Geodatabase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test it the layer uses service properties to create a connection to the data source.  That would mean its sources is either SDE or a Web service.

```
if lyr.supports("SERVICEPROPERTIES") == False:
```

Comment: Ah very clever. I was thinking there might bew a support that would indicate SDE - I'd never have thought of this one though. Thanks!